# Concatenate $rootScope and string in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if it was possible to do something such as this.

In the controller.

```
$rootScope.liveIn = "liveInCareHome";
```

HTML Snippet

```
ng-model='housingDetails + "." + liveIn'
```

This is so that the value of the input will be stored in housingDetails. Ie it would be the equivilent of having `ng-model="'housingDetails.liveInCareHome'"`

Full HTML

```
<ng-form id="housingDetailsngform" name="housingDetailsngform">
<section id="housingDetails" class="full-form">
    <div class="question">
        <div class="question-input ">
            <select required class="form-control" name="{{liveIn}}" ng-model='housingDetails + "." + liveIn'>
                <option value="co-ownership">Co-ownership</option>
                <option value="crownTenant">Crown tenant</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</ng-form>
```

Although I've looked online i can't seem to get a working version of this if one exists. Any other suggests are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your data-ng-model like these

Html

```
<select ng-model="housingDetails[liveIn]">
```

Controller

```
$rootScope.liveIn = "liveInCareHome";
```

Comment: Thanks worked although I had to removed the `' '` so that it used the name in $rootScope but the variable name.